# When deploying a Rails 3 app with Capistrano 2.5.19, what should be in shared/system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2, passenger, capistrano

I am running Passenger with Apache2 on Ubuntu.  I'm trying to get an idea what I should be looking at, and my suspicion lies with my Capistrano configuration / permissions.

My application seems to be deployed to current as expected.  I can see all the project files.  I see a symlink in the current/public directory to shared/system.  When I look at the contents of shared/system, there is nothing, no symlink or files.  Is this correct?  Is a symlink missing?

Capistrano deployment file:
https://github.com/danieldbower/passhasher/blob/master/config/deploy.rb

Logged message in Apache:
    Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.2 mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
    Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/passhasher/

Apache Config:
    Alias /passhasher /var/www-rails/passhasher/current/public
    <Directory /var/www-rails/passhasher/current/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default folder in which you keep all files not related to a particular version of your deployment.

I put the users' uploads inside.

Have a look here:

http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2007/03/13/stop-uploaded-files-getting-deleted-with-capistrano/

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if passenger was looking in this location for the "code", but I guess not.  I must have a incorrectly configured Apache.  On a side note, did I overlook a resource/manual which specifies what directories are created, and for which purpose?